# ItemTemplate in Listview - Layout issue

Tags: asp.net, css, itemtemplate

I have the following Listview in my aspx page

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" GroupItemCount="4" runat="server" 
     DataKeyNames="contentid" DataSourceID="sqldsPhotos">
<LayoutTemplate>
    <asp:Placeholder
    id="groupPlaceholder"
    runat="server" />
</LayoutTemplate>
<GroupTemplate>
    <div>
    <asp:Placeholder
    id="itemPlaceholder"
    runat="server" />
    </div>
</GroupTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>

    <asp:Image id="picAlbum" runat="server" 
         ImageUrl='<%# "ShowImage.ashx?id=" + Convert.ToString(Eval("contentid")) %>'   
         Height="108" Width="192" />
    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server">LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>
    </ItemTemplate>
<EmptyItemTemplate>           

</EmptyItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

The resulting webpage displays my image with the link button beside it. What I would like is the image with the Linkbutton centered below it for each item.

Can someone help me out with the necessary html or css to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following html inside `ItemTemplate`

```
<div style="float: left; margin-left: 10px; text-align:center;width: 192; ">
    <asp:Image id="picAlbum" runat="server" 
         ImageUrl='<%# "ShowImage.ashx?id=" + Convert.ToString(Eval("contentid")) %>'   
         Height="108" Width="192" />
    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server"
         style="display: block; clear: both;">LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>
</div>
```

The above code will show divs side by side. So inorder to show 4 divs add with (800px) to your items in list view.

If you don't get the linkbutton at center add some `margin-left` to it to show it at center.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not get me what I need. My picture and link are still side by side. This markup just centeres them in the container. What I need is the link centered below the picture.  This is what it originally looked like [before](http://stackstuff.tumblr.com/image/28976949852) and this is what it looks like after adding the div tag [after](http://stackstuff.tumblr.com/image/28976962386)

Comment: I am looking to have the photo with the link below it and go across with this 4 times per row.

Comment: You should add these points in question. Otherwise how someone will know, what do you need. I have changed the answer accordingly. Let me know if anything else is required.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div style="width: 192px; text-align:center;">
    <asp:Image id="picAlbum" runat="server" 
         ImageUrl='<%# "ShowImage.ashx?id=" + Convert.ToString(Eval("contentid")) %>'   
         Height="108" Width="192" /><br/>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server">LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>
</div>
```